# Adding object into LinkedList C++

Tags: c++

I can't figure out notation, confused with reference and pointers. I have to put Student pointers into LinkedList. And I think I just put wrong & or *. Here what I do:

```
int main(){
PointerClass *p = new PointerClass();
Student *s = new Student();
p->add(s);
return 0;
}
```

On `add` as I see error:

> a reference of type “Student&” (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized

above `add` is defined as this

```
void PointerClass::add(Student& a) {
    ll.AddNode(a);
}
```

where `ll` is:

```
private:
    LinkedList ll;
```

Class LinkedList has following structure:

```
class LinkedList
{
private:
    typedef struct node {
        Student data;
        node* next;
    }* nodePtr;


    nodePtr head;
    nodePtr curr;
    nodePtr temp;
}

void LinkedList::AddNode(Student& addData) {
    nodePtr n = new node;
    n->next = NULL;
    n->data = addData;

    if (head != NULL) {
        curr = head;
        while (curr->next != NULL) {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = n;
    }
    else {
        head = n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `void PointerClass::add(Student *a) {` and `void LinkedList::AddNode(Student *addData) {`

Comment: This is rather poor C++ code. Consider switching to a good and modern C++ book as your learning resource, or supplement what ever you are learning from atm with one at least.

Comment: Adding to what @BaummitAugen said, here is a [list of some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/9254539). Did nobody ever tell you that `main()` returns an int?

Comment: @FeiXiang that is not main point here. I was trying to grab parts of code into here, so that not to clutter too much, so that is just a trivial typo which doesn't make question wrong at all

Comment: @DimChtz ,  thank you . I guess now I understand how stuff works. I did another minor change in struct and that worked as intended

Comment: @BaummitAugen , thanks for comment, I'm just learning concepts. And if you mention what parts are poor that would be great. PS. I didn't put whole code here, so maybe because i put parts that looks not so great

Comment: @Sher Littering everything with pointers and having naked `new`s at all are quite an antipattern, for starters.

Comment: @BaummitAugen, maybe. But I have to do this stuff on heap rather than on stack and i also have to practice those pointers. :(

Answer (score 0):

Your functions `PointerClass::add()` and `LinkedList::addNode()` are expecting a `Student` as a parameter, not a `Student*`. You have two options to make it work:

1) Refactor `PointerClass::add()` and `LinkedList::addNode()` to receive and store a `Student*`. This would basically amount to replacing the `&`s in the function parameter declarations with `*`s and either de-referencing that pointer when you put it in your new `LinkedList::node`, or changing the type of `LinkedList::node::data` to `Student*`

2) Pass a `Student` to `PointerClass::add()`. This would just be a matter of declaring `s` with something like `Student s = Student();`, or de-referencing it before passing it to `PointerClass::add()`.